# Why my project is not getting uploaded to github from visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013

I am using github with visual studio 2013. I have an account and a repository on github. I have committed local changes in visual studio but it's not getting published to online git account.

Error:**current branch does not have an upstream branch configured**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [current branch does not have an upstream branch configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269146/current-branch-does-not-have-an-upstream-branch-configured)

Comment: i used that solutions but none worked

Comment: A commit just commits locally. You need to push the changes to the upstream repository.

Comment: yes but how ? I tried many things

Comment: @PostingQuestions you should mention that when posting your question - it will save us from linking duplicates and you from getting useless comments. Include everything you already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try it that way: 
In the team manager select branches. Select your local branch -> right click and select push.

You should see the result in your console. Please post the error message you are receiving, if this does not work.